# Could not run the latex MikTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex2.9

I am using latex from last 4 years and had written thesis on latex. But, today when I executed my thesis it gives following error

```
Error: Could not start the command: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mainrep".tex
```

I have reinstall latex and MikTeX2.9, but still, the same error occurs.
Please do the required help.

Comment: Try to call xelatex from a command line to get a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer the problem was regarding the path setting of MikTek. I reinstalled MikTek and set its environment C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin. Then the program runs successfully.